# Why this is not valid regular expression

Tags: java, regex, web-services

I am facing following exception while parsing this `'((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))'` regular expression

```
WARNING: Exception message: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/u/bin/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.7/webapps/MyService/schema/version/1.2.35/RequestSchema.xsd; 
lineNumber: 1928; columnNumber: 38; InvalidRegex: Pattern value '((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key parser.factor.0' at column '{2}'.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4124)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4107)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.reportSchemaError(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:721)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.getSimpleType(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:406)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseSimpleTypeDecl(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:163)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:104)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1431)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:619)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:588)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:555)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:521)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:240)
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I  think it is because of `,`. because it is a special character. Try to use it like this `[\,]`

Comment: @viktorovich: This shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last closing parentheses is unmatched. Try removing it:

```
'((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z])'
```

Or matching it:

```
'(((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
'(((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))'
```

You had some parentheses missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing bracket at last place of your regex. Remove it and then try

```
((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have six ")" and only five "("

```
'(((([A-Z][,]+)+)([A-Z]?))|([A-Z]))'
```

Regards
Hugo Pedrosa